# Play a video uploaded on OneDrive on Flutter

Tags: flutter, video, video-streaming, onedrive

Is there a way to play or stream a video on Flutter from a video uploaded on OneDrive through its url without downloading it?
Or is there a way to access direct video url (.mp4) from OneDrive?